# expected init-declarator before "type" in templated typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I am trying to complie the code below.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class class1
{
typedef T1 Type1;
typedef T2 Type2;
//void class1Method();
};


template <class T1>
class class2
{
typedef T1 Type1;
void class2Method();
};

template <class T1>
void class2<T1>::class2Method()
{
 typedef class1<T1,T1>::Type1 Type3;
}
```

However, I get the error shown below.

```
g++ -g -c class12.h -o class12.o
class12.h: In member function `void class2<T1>::class2Method()':
class12.h:20: error: expected init-declarator before "Type3"
class12.h:20: error: expected `,' or `;' before "Type3"
make: *** [class12.o] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Can somebody please let me know?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `typename`

```
typedef typename class1<T1,T1>::Type1 Type3;
```

Furthermore, you need to make the typedef in `class1` public.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class class1
{
 public:
  typedef T1 Type1;
  typedef T2 Type2;
};
```

Comment: d'oh - beat me to it.

Comment: @juanchopanza do you mean I can define a type within a function scope?

Comment: @geraldCelente Yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `typename`:

```
typedef typename class1<T1,T1>::Type1 Type3;
```